# Smarty - Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, smarty

I added some rewrite rules in Apache Config file to build semantic URL. The problem is i want to do it at root level so that URL look like `domain.com/about-us` but with this All the style-sheets, java-script and images do not load. Although i am using absolute paths.
but when i redirect with `domain.com/pages/about-us` it works all fine.
This is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) /index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: you need to set the condition that rewirting starts only if it is not a file ......

Comment: are you talking about this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: *RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f* you got it

Comment: even this is not working

Comment: Thanks For Answering i solved it myself
    RewriteRule ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC]